# Cadsoft Eagle Library: How to create device variant?

Tags: eaglecad, library

I'm creating a custom device in Eagle Library.
Generally I need two device, let's say they're CONN2.54_1 and CONN2.54_2.
These two devices are connectors, they both have 4 pins, thus they have the same symbol. The difference is the package, one is vertical mount and one is horizontal.

Now I can create 2 separate device successfully. However I want to know how to group them under one "sub-category" in the Library?

For example: when I use the add button in the Schematic Editor, my custom Library should appear like:

---

MY_LIBRARY\           (This is the main library)

---

```
  CONN2.54\       (There's a sub-folder name CONN2.54)
```

---

```
      CONN2.54_1  (The first device is inside the sub-category)
      CONN2.54_2  (The second device is also inside the sub-category)
```

---

Thank you!

Comment: Typically you would create one device and assign it two packages.  If you are having issues with it not letting you do that, make sure you are giving the second variant a variant name - the default only works for the first package option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the library editor, go to your device and you'll see the traditional screen.  Here is the "rcl" library - probably the most popular library there is.

[image]

On the right side is the package variant section.  Here is where you can assign multiple packages to the same device.  You simply click on "New," select your new package, give it a useful name, and add it.  You can then associate schematic pins to footprint pins with the "Connect" button. You can see in rcl how the resistors use one schematic part but a large number of package variants.